# C# Listar elementos Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente problema

`total = await _context.Inspections.Include(p => p.Measurements.Where(e=> e.MaterialId == idMaterial)).ToListAsync();`

Inspections es una tabla de la base de datos que contiene una lista de Measurements.
Esto lo que hace es meterme en la lista esa Measurement referente a la inspeccion cuando lo que quiero es que solo que un elemento de Measurements de la lista de esa Inspection coincida quiero toda la Inspection no solo el elemento sde la lista que coincide.
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola!! La verdad es que me parece un poco liosa la explicación que das. ¿Podrías, por favor, detallar un poco mas que contiene cada entidad y que es lo que quieres conseguir? Disculpa, pero es que sino no consigo entenderlo.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo con @cjimenecue, Dices que Measurements es una lista embedida de Insections osea que tiene una relacion uno (Inpections) a muchos(measurements)? trata de hacer un inner join de las 2 tablas y realiza la busqueda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, la propiedad "Measurements" en tu modelo "Inspections" es una referencia de relación de tipo [N - 1], es decir, a 1 mismo "Measurement" podrás tener N "Inspections".
Si lo que necesitas es una relación [1 - N] o [1 - 1] deberás cambiar tu modelado de BBDD.

Ese .Where(e=> e.MaterialId == idMaterial) debería ser una entrada en tu "Context" del tipo :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Measurements>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Inspection)
        .WithMany(b => b.Measurements)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.MaterialId);
```